# What is the gerund phrase?

Tags: gerunds

What is the gerund phrase in the sentence, "Bearing is the precious seed of the gospel to others will bring its reward." And what is it used as?

Comment: I think this should be "Bearing the precious seed ..." Do you understand it now?

Answer (score 2):

The gerund is formed from the verb but it acts like a noun.

For example, we have the verb "to bring", which can mean "to carry something to someone". The present-participle form of the verb, **bringing**, can be used as a noun:

> **Bringing** food to the workers was his job.

We call that noun-from-verb a gerund.

The marked infinitive can also be used nominally:

> His job was **to bring** food to the workers.

Both the participle and the infinitive refer to the *abstract idea* of the verb's action, rather than to the action actually as it happens or is performed at a particular moment by a particular actor:

> He crossed the busy street at 5PM.
>
> Crossing a busy street can be dangerous.
>
> To cross a busy street can be dangerous.

In conversation, it is more natural to use the -**ing** form than the marked infinitive in this role; you will hear speakers using the so-called "dummy it" in combination with the marked infinitive:

> **It** can be dangerous **to cross** a busy street.